# What are the reasons to use ERC-1155 instead of multiple ERC-20 contracts?

Tags: erc-20, erc-1155

The ERC-1155 standard allows for multiple semi-fungible tokens.

If I understand correctly, this would be no different than creating multiple ERC-20 contracts, with the same token quantities, to represent the digital goods. The only benefit is having everything in the same place.

Are there other reasons to use ERC-1155 instead of multiple ERC-20 contracts?

Answer (score 3):

ERC-1155 tends to be more useful for things such as games that need both fundable (In-game gold) and non-fungible(land) tokens.

Comment: Why would a game creator one ERC-1155 contract, instead of creating multiple individual ERC-20 and ERC-721 contracts?

Answer (score 3):

> The only benefit is having everything in the same place.

ERC-1155 is orders of magnitude more gas efficient, as deploying an ERC-20 contract is costly with current Ethereum gas prices.

Comment: So switching to 1155 at least saves the gas required to initialize multiple new ERC-20 tokens?

Comment: This is correct.

Comment: why not just use a proxy pattern instead?

Comment: Because proxy pattern solves a different problem